# How to start Memgraph database on Ubuntu?

Tags: memgraphdb

I know that there are two ways to run Memgraph on Ubuntu:

1. `sudo systemctl start memgraph`
2. `sudo service memgraph start`

Is there a preferred way to run Memgraph?

I've seen that if Ubuntu is run as WSL that the command for running it is `sudo runuser -l memgraph -c '/usr/lib/memgraph/memgraph'`. Can I use this command also on standalone Ubuntu installation, or is this one only for WSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `systemctl` interacts with `systemd` which is an init(and manager) system. When the Linux kernel is booted, there are some services that must start, etc. These are managed by `systemd` which is controlled by `systemctl`. `service` is the same as `systemctl` but for **older systems** which do not use `systemd` as their init system.
2. This command is simply running the executable placed in `/usr/lib/memgraph/memgraph` with the user `memgraph`.

The difference between these two is that the latter one won't start on the startup while the first one will.